# How to add strings to a list and print the list?

Tags: python, list, oop

I want to create a program where it works like a simple bag. You can add items to the bag (in this case is strings) into a list. Here's my code:

```
class Items:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
class Bag:
    def __init__(self, items, max_items):
        # max_items is the maximum capacity of the Bag
        self.items = items
        self.max_items = max_items
    
    def add_items(self):
        if len(self.items) < self.max_items:
           self.items.append(i.name)
        
    def read_items(self):
        for item in self.items:
            print(item.name)

i = Items("Item1")
b = Bag([], 10) # I'm just going to put example 10 strings for the max_items
b.read_items()
```

From this code there is no output (just to be clear, I mean there's no input whatsoever, not the input "None").

My goal is to make the code run whatever is inside the list. In any conditions, even if there's items being added to the list.

Comment: You are not adding any items to the container with your `add_items` method, and therefore the `read_items` method has nothing to output.

Comment: Hey! Well you would need to append (insert) items to the list “self.items” first right? Also, you could just define the variable “self.items” inside the class as an attribute (self.items = [ ]) then append to it!

Comment: @JohnKugelman I see, I tried it again with a simpler 'for' loop mathod to read empty array, and the output is the word "None". But in this case, that class doesn't show any word or error at the same time. It just prints out "192:~ local$ /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/local/Desktop/Python/question.py" and asking for the next command. Meaning that my 'b.read_items()' isn't executed properly.

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi I understad, i applied it to my code and it works perfectly! Thanks so much for the help! I was really struggling with this!

Answer (score 0):

There are no calls to `add_items()`, and thus no items in the list.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help :)